# Is a connection to MongoDB automatically closed on process.exit()?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using the `mongodb` driver to connect to a MongoDB server from a Node.js application.

Supposed my application crashes, or I call `process.exit()`, *without* closing the connection previously - does it stay open? Is it closed automatically? If so, who cares about that? Node.js? The TCP/IP stack? MongoDB? …? And: When does that happen?

Does it make a difference if I hit `<Ctrl>+<C>`?

Comment: Are you able to run mongod and look at the output as process.exit() executes? We're using mongoose which does a fair bit of connection management so I doubt what I'd post would be accurate.

Answer (score 16):

The answer is **no**. DB connections don't gracefully shut down when you exit (or crash).

To do that you should use something similar to:

```
// Create a function to terminate your app gracefully:
function gracefulShutdown(){
    // First argument is [force], see mongoose doc.
    mongoose.connection.close(false, () => {
      console.log('MongoDb connection closed.');
    });
  });
}

// Ask node to run your function before exit:

// This will handle process.exit():
process.on('exit', gracefulShutdown);

// This will handle kill commands, such as CTRL+C:
process.on('SIGINT', gracefulShutdown);
process.on('SIGTERM', gracefulShutdown);
process.on('SIGKILL', gracefulShutdown);

// This will prevent dirty exit on code-fault crashes:
process.on('uncaughtException', gracefulShutdown);
```

There are also some packages to handle this behavior, but this is usually very straightforward, and simple to implement.

Comment: Note that newer versions of node will throw uv_signal_start EINVAL Error when you're trying to work with SIGKILL or SIGSTOP

Answer (score 1):

I've tested with `CTRL+C`, and the connections are closing automatically. The picture bellow shows connection after running `server.js` and after closing it. It shows that the current connection is 1 because i'm running `mongo` from terminal. Try it yourself!
[image: Mongo database instance from terminal]

[image]