# Node.js MongoDB crashes on Client.close()

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using latest Mongodb 3.5.7 with Node.js and Express,

What I do is I call an async function when an API is being called and the code is as following  :

```js
async function insert(data) {


        try {
             const connection = await client.connect();
             db =client.db(dbName);
             const insertion  = await db.collection('inserts').insertOne(data);
             //console.log(await client.close());
             await console.log('finished waiting promises');
             await client.close();
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.stack);
            return Promise.reject('false');
        }
        return new Promise(resolve =>{

            resolve();
        })
}
```

`
In fact the first API Call works so well and successfully inserts the data into db , the issue starts with the second try which brings this error

I also tried promises in separated functions with every command ( connect - insert -close ) with call back promise and await for each one to be done.

As well tried calling connecting function which i created.then(setdbname).then(insert).then(closedb) ...

```
the options [servers] is not supported
the options [caseTranslate] is not supported
the options [dbName] is not supported
the options [credentials] is not supported

MongoError: topology was destroyed
    at executeWriteOperation (C:\Users\raymo\Documents\Ticket\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\topologies\replset.js:1188:21)
    at ReplSet.insert (C:\Users\raymo\Documents\Ticket\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\topologies\replset.js:1257:3)
    at ReplSet.insert (C:\Users\raymo\Documents\Ticket\node_modules\mongodb\lib\topologies\topology_base.js:322:25)
    at insertDocuments (C:\Users\raymo\Documents\Ticket\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\common_functions.js:259:19)
    at InsertOneOperation.execute (C:\Users\raymo\Documents\Ticket\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\insert_one.js:26:5)
    at C:\Users\raymo\Documents\Ticket\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:98:26
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at executeOperation (C:\Users\raymo\Documents\Ticket\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:91:10)
    at Collection.insertOne (C:\Users\raymo\Documents\Ticket\node_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:516:10)
    at Object.insert (C:\Users\raymo\Documents\Ticket\routes\Handlers\DatabaseHandler.js:68:63)
```

as well I tried downgrading to mongo v. 3.4.0

I tried normal Callback functions and it works. but i need to upgrade and work with promises and await/async
Please suggest edits if my question is not clear.

Comment: You don't need to use `client.close()` at all. It is already handled. Continue using your current connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client.close()` closes the current db connection, including all the child db instances as stated in the [documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html). This means that once you've called it, the current mongo client can no longer be used. You'd need to create an entirely new MongoClient and call `connect()` on it.

But - you should not do this, there's no need to manually create/close the connection for every database operation.

Just keep your connection instance after doing `const connection = await client.connect();` and reuse/share it for your other operations. MongoClient already handles connection pooling for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ... So that won't create a load of connection pools ? meaning that if I removed the close() this will create a new connection whenever node calls this function ... with 1000 calls will create 1000 connections to mongodb ... am I correct?

Comment: or you mean connect in app.js and just pass the client ? but what If after a long time the server keeps on restarting for some reason wouldn't that create a bunch of connection pools  ?

Comment: @RaymondHaniArtin
You may like to read this section on how to handle pooling.
https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html#mongoclient-connection-pooling

Comment: Yes, here's how they recommend it: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html#mongoclient-connection-pooling

Comment: Yeah Great I got it but in this case if the server crashed for some reason will that close the db connection? or how shall I Handle this ?

Comment: Here's a post which poses the exact same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36979146/is-a-connection-to-mongodb-automatically-closed-on-process-exit
A quick test showed that the mongo-server closes the connection if I kill the node-script which has connected to the db though.